# Flow condition with payload that has an array in Directus

Tags: directus

I have the following payload in a form in Directus. I'm using a Flow to send an email to the supplied email address. However I don't want to send the email in case **some** of the people have attending set to false.

```
{
  "key": 188,
  "event": "submissions.items.create",
  "payload": {
    "email": "my@mail.be",
    "people": [
      {
        "title": "Dhr",
        "lastname": "Lastname",
        "attending": false,
        "firstname": "Myself"
      }
    ]
  },
  "collection": "submissions"
}
```

**I added a conditional flow block** between my trigger and the sending of the email. I only want to send an email if **some** of the people have attending set to true.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I tried the following, but got an error:

```
{
    "$trigger": {
        "payload": {
            "people": {
                "attending": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
"stack": "ValidationError: \"$trigger.payload.people\" must be of type object",
```